# Why is this Regular Expression Substition Substituting raw regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use re.sub to replace all the different combinations of B2Ab in this file with for this example B2Az.  The find part is working perfectly, but every time I do a substitution it substitutes the raw regular expression.  I am obviously missing something very simple but cannot find out what it is.

This is a snippet of the file I am parsing:

```
                    <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2058" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 11" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="GENB2AbE" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
                                                    <t:ION t:SA="RegisterObj" t:H="3978" t:P="2058" t:N="RE11 Data Log" t:CI="Log_Register" t:L="GENB2Ab">
                                                                            <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2059" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 12" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="B2Ab2SBrkr" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
                        <t:IH>
                            <t:CH t:H="43715">
                            </t:CH>
    <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2058" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 11" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="PMDC_B2_A_b_E" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
    <t:IH>
                            <t:CH t:H="43715">
                            </t:CH>
    <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2058" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 11" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="PMDC-B2-A-b_E" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
```

This is the latest iteration of my numerous attempts to get this to work:

```
var1 = 'B'
var2 = '2'
var3 = 'A'
var4 = 'b' 
var5 = 'z'                  
fname = 'example.txt'        
regexfind(fname,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5)

def regexfind(filename,varl1,varl2,varl3,varl4,varlr,):

    pattern = re.compile('([_-]?['+varl1+'][_-]?['+varl2+'][_-]?['+varl3+'][_-]?['+varl4+'][_-]?)')
    repl = re.compile('([_-]?['+varl1+'][_-]?['+varl2+'][_-]?['+varl3+'][_-]?['+varlr+'][_-]?)')

    f = open(filename,'rb')
    searchstrs = f.readlines()
    i=0
    for line in searchstrs:
        for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
                    print 'Found on line %s: %s' % (i+1, match.groups())
                    #Showing decompiled patterns for ease of explanation
                    line = re.sub(r'[_-]?['+varl1+'][_-]?['+varl2+'][_-]?['+varl3+'][_-]?['+varl4+'][_-]?',\
                                  r'[_-]?['+varl1+'][_-]?['+varl2+'][_-]?['+varl3+'][_-]?['+varlr+'][_-]?', line.rstrip())
                    print(line)
```

This is what I am getting for output from the above code:

```
 Found on line 1: ('B2Ab',)
 <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2058" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 11" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="GEN[_-]?[B][_-]?[2][_-]?[A][_-]?[z][_-]?E" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
 Found on line 1: ('B2Ab',)
 <t:ION t:SA="RegisterObj" t:H="3978" t:P="2058" t:N="RE11 Data Log" t:CI="Log_Register" t:L="GEN[_-]?[B][_-]?[2][_-]?[A][_-]?[z][_-]?">
 Found on line 1: ('B2Ab',)
 <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2059" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 12" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="[_-]?[B][_-]?[2][_-]?[A][_-]?[z][_-]?2SBrkr" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
 Found on line 1: ('_B2_A_b_',)
 <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2058" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 11" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="PMDC[_-]?[B][_-]?[2][_-]?[A][_-]?[z][_-]?E" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
 Found on line 1: ('-B2-A-b_',)
 <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2058" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 11" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="PMDC[_-]?[B][_-]?[2][_-]?[A][_-]?[z][_-]?E" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
```

I should be getting this:

```
 Found on line 1: ('B2Ab',)
 <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2058" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 11" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="GENB2AzE" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
 Found on line 1: ('B2Ab',)
 <t:ION t:SA="RegisterObj" t:H="3978" t:P="2058" t:N="RE11 Data Log" t:CI="Log_Register" t:L="GENB2Az">
 Found on line 1: ('B2Ab',)
 <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2059" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 12" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="B2Az2SBrkr" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
 Found on line 1: ('_B2_A_b_',)
 <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2058" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 11" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="PMDC_B2_A_z_E" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
 Found on line 1: ('-B2-A-b_',)
 <t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2058" t:P="132" t:N="Data Rec 11" t:CI="DataRecorder_Module" t:L="PMDC_B2_A_z_E" t:S="1" t:SC="5">
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions as to what I am missing here.

Comment: Because that's what you're telling it to do with the second argument of `re.sub`.

Answer (score 2):

The replacement is not a pattern. Its only special feature is that it replaces sequences `\1`, `\2` etc. with capture group contents. So you can't match underscores and dashes in the replacement part; you want to copy them from the pattern.

```
pattern = re.compile('([_-]?'+varl1+'[_-]?'+varl2+'[_-]?'+varl3+'[_-]?)'+varl4+'([_-]?)')
re.sub(pattern, r'\1' + varlr + r'\2', line.rstrip())
```

On e.g. `"PMDC_B2_A_b_E"`, this will capture `"_B2_A_` and `"_"` into `\1` and `\2` respectively, then restore them back in the replacement, with `z` sandwiched in between, for final `_B2_A_z_` replacement, making the final string `"PMDC_B2_A_z_E"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a replacement function of your own.

```
def repl(matchobj):
     return varl1+varl2+varl3+valr4

line = re.sub(r'[_-]?['+varl1+'][_-]?['+varl2+'][_-]?['+varl3+'][_-]?['+varl4+'][_-]?',repl, line.rstrip())
```

Something of this sort.In function you can return anything you want.

Comment: This still gives weird `[_-]?` stuff in replacement - not what the OP wants. See "I should be getting this".

Comment: @Jerry i have said something of this sort.........so he can modify as per his wish

Comment: @vks At this rate, the OP will have to modify *everything*. I fail to see how that is helpful in any way.